# How can I create a magic shopping cart for B2B?

Tags: algorithm, performance, machine-learning, comparison, e-commerce

I work in a B2B e-commerce company and we want improve our user experience with a function called **"Magic shopping cart"**.

Let me explain :

Our website is a marketplace with *multiple sellers selling* a range of products with a *limited stock per product*, the point of our function is to make our customers find the **cheapest cart** for all the products they wish to buy.
At the moment customers need to search through all the website to find the best prices and to regroup a maximum of products on the same seller to reduce shipping fees.

We are searching for an algorithm that does all the research for our customers, meaning finding **the best combination of sellers and products** in order to buy the cheapest products.

We have done a function that combines all possible shopping cart for given products and quantities than we test which one is the cheapest, this is flawless except it takes way too much time.
We need a quicker/ more efficient way to find the cheapest cart, we have thought of machine learning (we are no experts) but we are open to all ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Conventional algorithms offer better speed in most cases as compared to machine learning algorithms. If the customer wishes particular goods, and there is already a list of ALL offerings of these goods, then you just need an efficient search algorithm.

Machine learning would help you to identify which goods match which classes, for example, but this is not the problem you are trying to solve apparently.

Perhaps you are looking for some trade-off between the speed and quality of the magic cart feature (not optimum, but a good solution). In such case, there just might be space for using some machine learning, but it takes more specific formulation of the search task to come up with specific algorithm!
You might as well look into evolutionary algorithms and other optimization methods.

Comment: Hi Ikamen,

Thanks for your insight, we do have a list of all the goods, our main problem is that we need a response time that it is suitable for web users.

The fact that goods and quantities can be split on many sellers makes the number of combination a real problem.

Comment: @flex97115 So how does your current search algorithm look like? I suggest you post it into the question to give people a chance to improve it.